# SQL update time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Simple table

```
Time        NameTime
00:00:01     NULL
00:58:00     NULL
01:02:12     NULL
01:59:00     NULL
02:01:12     NULL
02:55:00     NULL
```

Query

```
SELECT  MIN(time) AS MinTime, Max(time) AS MaxTime
from table
group  by 
    DATEPART(HOUR, time)
     order by MinTime
```

Outcome

```
MinTime         MaxTime        NewTime
00:00:01        00:58:00        NULL
01:02:12        01:59:00        NULL
02:01:12        02:55:00        NULL
```

Need to update so column NewTime look like this. Mean group between hours and update name to newtime column. Thank you

```
MinTime         MaxTime        NewTime
00:00:01        00:58:00        0hrs
01:02:12        01:59:00        1hrs
02:01:12        02:55:00        2hrs
```

Comment: Look at `DATEPART`.

Comment: Your query cannot generate this output. It generates only one row, because it has no `group by` clause.

Comment: Sorry for typo, update query.

Comment: I will use CASE to update, not a best solution but it works. Thank all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a `case` expression. The first comment is the way to go. The `datepart()` function is already part of your query in the `group by` clause...

**Sample data**

```
create table MyData
(
  MyTime time
);

insert into MyData (MyTime) values
('00:00:01'),
('00:58:00'),
('01:02:12'),
('01:59:00'),
('02:01:12'),
('02:55:00');
```

**Solution**

```
select MIN(MyTime) AS MinTime, 
       Max(MyTime) AS MaxTime,
       DATEPART(HOUR, MyTime) as Hour,
       convert(nvarchar(2), DATEPART(HOUR, MyTime)) + 'hrs' as NewTime
from MyData
group by DATEPART(HOUR, MyTime)
order by MinTime;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=476d5b95e8c38060f71d0e7f89688a11)

Comment: Way to go. Thank you.